# SESSION doesn't get SET PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem guys. When i login, it does it fine. It says that you are logged in as $username = admin ... but when i refresh the login page it doesn't say that anymore. It gives me back the login and password fields so i could log back in. Im guessing the Session is not getting set but i can't seem to find the problem . It even says that my password is incorrect but still gives me you are logged in as admin which is my username Thanks

```
<?php

session_start();
include("connect.php");

if ($_POST['submit']){

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    if($username){

        if($password){

            $password =     md5(md5("KmsdufIFNKSnefndbdo19228330293".$password."JSDSHBFJS8S8ds8sd8s8d"));
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE      username='$username'");             
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

            if ($num_rows == 1){

                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                $db_username = $row['username'];
                $db_password = $row['password'];

                if ($password == $db_password){

                    $username =$_SESSION['username'];

                }else
                    echo "Your password is incorrect";

            }else{

                echo "Username not Found";

            }

        }

    }else
        echo "Futeni emrin e llogarise.";
}
?>
 <html>
 <head>

 </head>

<body>

<?php

if ($username){

    echo "You are logged in as, ".$username."!. <a href='logout.php'>LogOut</a> ";

}else{

    echo "

    <form action='login.php' method='post'>

        Username: <input type='text' name='username' id='user'/>
        <br/>
        Password: <input type='password' name='password' id='pass'/>
        <br/>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>

    </form>

    ";
}
?>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: where are you setting the session variables?

Comment: right after i validate that my password is correct

Comment: When you do `if($username)`, it is using the `$username` variable you initially populated from `$_POST`, so it is always set even if the db query failed. That's why it says "you are logged in as admin" even though you are not..

Comment: You are not setting the session variable.

Comment: $username = $_SESSION['username']; right after i validate that password that i entered is the same as password in DB

Comment: You probably need to reverse that assignment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value of $username is set inside `if ($_POST['submit']){` so, when you refresh the login page, it doesn't say that anymore. You should set `$username` to session

```
<?php

session_start();
include("connect.php");

if ($_POST['submit']){

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    if($username){

        if($password){

            $password =     md5(md5("KmsdufIFNKSnefndbdo19228330293".$password."JSDSHBFJS8S8ds8sd8s8d"));
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE      username='$username'");             
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

            if ($num_rows == 1){

                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                $db_username = $row['username'];
                $db_password = $row['password'];

                if ($password == $db_password){

                   $_SESSION['username']= $username;

                }else
                    echo "Your password is incorrect";

            }else{

                echo "Username not Found";

            }

        }

    }else
        echo "Futeni emrin e llogarise.";
}
?>
 <html>
 <head>

 </head>

<body>

<?php

if ( isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] != '' ){

   $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    echo "You are logged in as, ".$username."!. <a href='logout.php'>LogOut</a> ";

}else{

    echo "

    <form action='login.php' method='post'>

        Username: <input type='text' name='username' id='user'/>
        <br/>
        Password: <input type='password' name='password' id='pass'/>
        <br/>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>

    </form>

    ";
}
?>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: i see what i did there... thanks man .. you got it

Comment: @user2488317 If it helps you please give up vote and accept the answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to set `username` into `session` variable

```
if ($password == $db_password){

   $username =      mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

} else {
   echo "Your password is incorrect";
}
```

In `if` condition you need to change the following code

```
$username = isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : null;
if ($username){

    echo "You are logged in as, ".$username."!. <a href='logout.php'>LogOut</a> ";

}else{

   /* your code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the other way. Try

```
if ($password == $db_password){

                    $_SESSION['username'] =  $username;

}
```

then

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
  echo "You are logged in as, $_SESSION['username']!. <a href='logout.php'>LogOut</a>";
}
```

P.S Start using prepared statements (mysqli or pdo) and avoid mysql extension.